# How do set a layer on an ECS entity?

Tags: unity, entity-component-system, unity-dots

I'm using Unity ECS entities to draw out some tiles. I would like to determine the layer (or sortOrder) of the rendered tile so that if a tile is placed over another at the same position, the tile with the higher layer value will be visible.

It appears random at the moment. I tried:

```
entityManager.SetSharedComponentData(entity, new RenderMesh
{
   mesh = mesh,
   material = mat,
   layer = level
});
```

But it didn't seem to do anything.